# Typescript inference of parameter type doesn't work in concrete implementation of abstract class

Tags: typescript, abstract-class, type-inference

In the following code, Typescript cannot infer the type of `x`, unless I add a return type to the concrete `getMethods` implementation.

I would assume that inference is possible, since the abstract class defines the return type of `getMethods` as a `Methods` object, and the `Methods` object defines the type of `x` as a string.

Is this a shortcoming of the compiler, or is inference impossible here due to some reason?

```
interface Methods {
  [key: string]: (x: string) => void
}

abstract class Base {
  abstract getMethods(): Methods
}

class SomeClass extends Base {
  getMethods() {
    return {
      foo(x) {
        // x is inferred to be "any" instead of a "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```